# Java time to run code in ns

Tags: java

I am trying to find the time taken by the Java code to run, I am creating some huge object and want to track the time to the precision of nano seconds, if I use regular time stamp it says the code compiled in 0 seconds. Thanks

Comment: You may need to time this multiple times to get an accurate figure.

Comment: I get this error The method nanoTime() is undefined for the type System

Answer (score 6):

```
    long start = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("Hello World!");

    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(end - start);
```

[The docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29)

**edit**
*it says the code compiled in 0 seconds*
So, do you want compilation time or running time?

Comment: Both wold be great..running time matters

Comment: I get this error The method nanoTime() is undefined for the type System

Comment: @user357349 In the API docs for the method you can see "Since: 1.5". What Java version are you using?

Answer (score 5):

You need to take a look at

```
System.nanoTime()
```

The docs do say that nanosecond accuracy cannot be guaranteed, but it will give you more accurate results than 0seconds.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()